# Is it possible to convert two iterations into 'itertools.chain' operation in Python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm reading a Python book and encountered 'itertools.chain'. I am wondering if it is possible to convert following code regarding a 2D-array to 'itertools.chain'.

My second question is: what is the benefit of using 'itertools.chain' compared to two for-loops?

```
for row in range(rows):
    some operation on rows
    for col in range(columns):
        some operations on cell i,j
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about some concrete input and desired output? It would help in understanding what you want to do.

Comment: No, you can think of `chain` as the equivalent of *chaining* for-loops, one after the other. You want `for row, col in itertools.product(range(rows), range(columns)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the answer! What is the benefit of using 'itertools.chain/product' compare to 2 for-loops?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ My concrete example is a bit messy. Probably not easy to understand, related to some math computation. I think it's easier to put that way. But thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't use `chain` here, because `chain` would run once for each row, then once for each column (#rows + #cols), not for each cell (#rows * #cols).

What you want is `itertools.product`. But it only works if you're operating on the cells individually; if you need to perform a per-row operation, you're better off with the explicit nested loop. The `product` approach would be:

```
for row, col in itertools.product(range(rows), range(columns)):
    some operations on cell row,col
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is the benefit of using 'itertools.chain/product' compare to 2 for-loops?

Comment: @LeiHao: It can also be incrementally faster; e.g. in this case, you only create two `range` objects, not `#rows + 1` `range` objects (the nested loops could do this too, by creating a single `range(columns)` outside the loop and reusing it, but that's even more verbose and ugly). But the improvement is trivial; make the decision based on readability/functionality, performance microoptimizations like that are rarely worth it.